# VPN connection problems regarding plex media server and voice over IP

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing, openvpn, telephony

I have a home server - running Debian Jessie and plex media server. My router (fritzbox) allows all smartphones in my LAN to receive incoming landline calls (due to a certain app). This part works great.

I also installed OpenVPN, which allows me to access all of my files and also most of the services (samba, apache, tomcat, ...), which are running on my home server, from the outside. However, two problems remain: Neither can I access my plex media server nor can I make or receive any landline calls* via the respective smartphone apps.

Although I don't have much experience with network configurations, my suspicion is that I need to setup some kind of static route, so not only my clients in the virtual network can reach the server, but also the server can reach the clients.

My home network uses 192.168.1.0 (I know this is not ideal) with 192.168.1.1 beeing my home server and my vpn-network uses 10.8.0.0, again with 10.8.0.1 beeing my home server.

I added the following route to my ip table without success:

```
route add -net 10.8.0.0 gw 10.8.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev tun0
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

UPDATE 1:

* I cannot receive any calls via VPN connection. I can, however, make a call so a third phone will ring. However, if that phone is picked up, the line remains silent.

**UPDATE 2:**

Another important observation: I can ping the server from any client in the virtual network, but I **cannot** reach any client from the server!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your network configuration is invalid somehow.
You should be able to ping every client from the server.
Are you sure that your client firewall allow ping requests by the way?

Other than that you need to add route to the network 10.8.0.0/24 with gateway 10.8.0.1 on ALL your devices or on your default gateway, so your home network devices can route traffic to the OpenVPN server.

Or you can configure NAT on your OpenVPN server instead.

Take a look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/how-to-work-from-anywhere-using-vpn.html) for the examples how to configure both.